# is it safe to read the pipe when the other side is writing to it?

Tags: c++, winapi, communication, pipe

```
      fSuccess = ReadFile( 
         hPipe,    // pipe handle 
         chBuf,    // buffer to receive reply 
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),  // size of buffer 
         &cbRead,  // number of bytes read 
         NULL);    // not overlapped
```

If not safe, how can I ensure the other side is not writing when reading a pipe in windows?

Comment: Whats certainly not safe is reading/writing TCHARS. Because a different process is on the other side, it may be compiled with unicode on or off.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a perfectly legal operation on the pipe.  One end of the pipe can read from and write to a pipe irrespective of what is happening to the other end.

Comment: What if the other side has already quit when you are writing to the pipe?

Comment: What if the other side is too slow reading from the pipe, and the buffer is full when you are writing to the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe -- pipes handle all the necessary synchronization on the buffers and such automatically. If you try to write to/read from a pipe when the other process has closed its connection to the pipe (either explicitly by closing the pipe, or implicitly by exiting the process) you'll get `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` from `GetLastError`. If you're using anonymous pipes the parent process will typically look for this to detect when the child process exited, so there will be no more data to process.

Comment: What if the other side is too slow reading from the pipe, and the buffer is full when you are writing to the pipe?

Comment: @wamp: if memory serves, the kernel will expand the buffer -- up to a point. If the buffer is full and it's already at maximum size, I think the attempted write just blocks, though I don't remember for certain.